# App launches a blank screen after creating a new target in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, mobile

I was having some problems getting a target archive to validate so I decided to delete the target and make a fresh one. Problem solved the app validates just fine but now it launches a blank screen and hangs there. Can anyone give me some pointers on this? I have been searching the internet for hours and I'm drawing a blank. Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you're using storyboards, does this target have a default storyboard set to load?

Comment: I am using storyboards but I have not seen a setting for this in the target, do you know what the setting is called? I searched "storyboard" in xcode....

Comment: Main storyboard base filename is set to "MainStoryboard"

Comment: If you click on the project file in the file explorer you get the project settings view.  On the left side of that view you can select your different targets and at the top you have different groups of project settings.  Select your new target, and then select the "Summary" settings.  In there near the top there is a group for "iPad/iPhone Deployment info".  Within that section there is an entry for "Main Storyboard"  Is that filled in?

Comment: If you created a new target, then the resources might not be added to it, thus there is no MainStoryboard to load. You can check under `Build Phases` in the new target properties.

Comment: The main storyboard field is filled in. Andrei I have checked build phases and the storyboard is listed under "Copy Bundle Resource." Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. I will think of something else :|